# Legal notices for 3D printing

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, business, trademark

Recently I've faced a business plan description, where someone suggested to start business of 3D printing. And one of the use-cases is to print models of movies, comics characters and so on.

And my question is: is it legal to print a model (model is developed by businessman himself) of such characters for sale without permission?

Answer (score 2):

To use the likeness of any copyrighted material you will need to either own the copyright or have a licence from the copyright holder to do so. It is the same as if you were selling paintings of copyrighted material.

Comment: The question is also tagged with "trademark". Could you add some information about trademark issues?

Comment: So that "ideal" model is based on purchasing licences, which are pretty expensive?

Comment: There is no difference (in these terms) between copyrighted and trademarked material